# How to get values from table if they contains substrings from values in another table via pandas (dataframe) in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, substring

dear friends) is there any right way to do that in pandas?

first table:

```
N   COLOR
1   117116C25
2   117116C28
3   JP-1989-1-9
```

second table:

```
ART
SH034-117116C28
SH091B-117116C28
SH091B-JP-1989-1-9
SH077-117116c28
```

to get dataframe like that (only art with substring from first table)?:

```
N   COLOR   ART
2   117116C28   SH034-117116C28
2   117116C28   SH091B-117116C28
2   117116C28   SH077-117116c28
3   JP-1989-1-9 SH091B-JP-1989-1-9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the dataframes are named `df1` and `df2`, you can extract the part and `merge`:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='COLOR',
          right_on=df2['ART'].str.split('-', 1).str[1].str.upper(),
          how='right')
```

output:

```
   N        COLOR                 ART
0  2    117116C28     SH034-117116C28
1  2    117116C28    SH091B-117116C28
2  3  JP-1989-1-9  SH091B-JP-1989-1-9
3  2    117116C28     SH077-117116c28
```

Comment: Thanks, it almost work but if ART will be like that SH0-91B-117116C28 or x-x-117116C28-x

Comment: For the first one you can take the last item of the split, for the second example it starts to be ambiguous and you have to better define the conditions for matching (is **any** substring sufficient to have a match?)